# SOAP request in Perl

Tags: perl, soap, request, wsdl

I have to make SOAP request in Perl to some web service.

Details what I have:

- URL of website: https://example.com/integration/webServices/api?wsdl
- Name of service: importSheet
- Parameters for calling service: importSheetRequest
- userId: 123456
- apiKey: abcdefgh123456

This is example of SOAP:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://webeph/wsdl/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:importSheetRequest>
         <auth>
            <!-- auth data (userId and apiKey) -->
         </auth>
         <EPH>
            <!-- some custom params -->
         </EPH>
         <contract>true</contract>
      </ns1:importSheetRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And this is code in Perl so far, but it is bad, I was looking for tutorials but I don't understand it, so I would be very happy for any help.

```
    my $soap = SOAP::Lite->soapversion('1.2')->new(
        'service' => 'https://example.com/integration/webServices/api?wsdl',
        'timeout' => 600
    );
    $soap->transport->timeout(600);
    $soap->default_ns('https://example.com');
    $soap->on_action(
        sub
        { "https://example.com/integration/webServices/api?wsdl" }
    );
    my $request = $soap->call(
        'importSheet',
        SOAP::Data->name('userId')->value('123456'),
        SOAP::Data->name('apiKey')->value('abcdefgh123456'),
        SOAP::Data->name('contract')->value('true'),
    );


    my $result = $request ->result();

    print Dumper($result);
```

Error what I get is:

> -crashed with Service description 'https://example.com/integration/webServices/api?wsdl' can't be
>   loaded: 401 Unauthorized

So I think there is problem with authorization, so problem should be in this section:

```
 <auth>
    <!-- auth data (userId and apiKey) -->
 </auth>
```

So this:

```
    SOAP::Data->name('userId')->value('123456'),
    SOAP::Data->name('apiKey')->value('abcdefgh123456')
```

Should be nested in auth tag I think, but I don't know if it is the problem and how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You did not really ask a question. This is not the right place to ask for tutorial links. Please [edit] your question and ask for concrete help.

Comment: @simbabque I didn't ask for tutorial link, I was asking what is wrong with the code, please read it again, I said that I was looking for tutorials but it didn't help me so then I went here.

Comment: And yet, you have not told us what the code is supposed to be doing, what is happening, if there are any errors, or what you need help with, and you still have not asked a question. Why do you think your code is _bad_? Please take the [tour], read [ask] and then provide a [mcve]. We can only help if you give us more information.

Comment: @simbabque Thank you, I updated question.

Comment: Can you see the actual XML that being sent over the wire? Try using [LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::ConsoleLogger::Everywhere) to easily get that. Can you download the WSDL file to compare? I think a 401 would be rather that you need basic auth in the request that it does to get the WSDL in the first place. That's not an XML based request, but a simple HTTP GET.